# SSIS Sequence Container not executing each task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016

I am new to SSIS and am building a package to perform varies File System Tasks. All objects are working as intended with the exception of a group of Foreach Loop Containers that are within a single Sequence Container. The idea is that I want them to run simultaneously, but don't want the package to go to the next step until all have run.

These Foreach loops check for a specific wildcard within the file name and move it to another folder, renaming the file as well. When I execute each Foreach Loop manually (right click the container and hit Execute Container) the task is performed correctly confirmed by a green check mark on both the Container and the File System Task and I see the file was moved properly to the destination folder.

[image]

But when I try to execute the *entire* Sequence Container, only one file system task is completed successfully (seemingly random as it's different each time I try). Despite receiving all check marks, only one file was actually moved and renamed.

[image]

I also tried adding constraints to flow from one container to the next. This time the green check mark appears on all 5 containers but only the first File System Task is checked off (and was moved + renamed). It's as if the rest of tasks were skipped.

[image]

How can I ensure that all tasks are completed each time I run the package?

EDIT: Here are the execution results of my last run:

[image]

Comment: Do the 5 different loops/tasks share a common variable or connection in any of their expressions?

Comment: They are all using the same source folder variable, but no direct connections. They have their own destination variables.

Comment: Is the value of that shared variable expected to be different for each loop, or do they all in fact use the same source folder?

Comment: They pull files from the same folder (files we receive from a FTP site). I'm moving each category to their own destination.

Comment: In the ForeachFile Enumerator, you need unique filters for the "Files"..do you have those unique for each of those loops?

Comment: Is it possible that you are overwriting the entire folder? Instead of each file in the folder? That would make sense to get all those checks, but only one file "moved".

Comment: @DIWP The Enumerator type is the same "Foreach File Enumerator/" The Folder is the same for each, but the Files filter is different for all

Comment: @KeithL The folder still exists after it runs with 4 of the 5 files still there

Comment: I know I am throwing suggestions at you, but I found that a copy task and a delete task works better than a move.

Comment: I just tried that and it appeared to work at first, but when I checked the files it appears to be copying the same source file to 5 differently named destinations.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for For-Each loop to not execute is if the enumerator is empty. There is something happening after the first randomly selected FE loop that ensures that the rest of the F-Each loops have no enumerations. I would do the following:

- Put a variable value changed break-point on the variables used for
  source folder, and for each file that's being moved. I'd go to the
  length of putting a script task with a message box that shows the
  file path. Put these breakpoints on each loop.
- Ensure that your file path is fully qualified so that source used is indeed correct
- Check progress tab for details FE loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added a screenshot of the execution results in my post for reference. Does anything stand out?

Comment: Matt. Have you added variable watch and see their values change? That is one of the debugging methods that can help you narrow down the problem.